# Make icon and dropdown list item middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make the svg icon to be middle and the menu text and the gray text to appear on the right using bootstrap

[image]
I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/> <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/> </svg>        
&nbsp;Create new Workflow
</button>
        

<div class="dropdown-menu p-0 border-0" style="width: max-content;">
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="32" width="25.6"><path d="M6.36 25.2h12.88v-2.4H6.36zm0-6.8h12.88V16H6.36zM2.4 32q-.96 0-1.68-.72Q0 30.56 0 29.6V2.4Q0 1.44.72.72 1.44 0 2.4 0h14.44l8.76 8.76V29.6q0 .96-.72 1.68-.72.72-1.68.72zM15.64 9.84V2.4H2.4v27.2h20.8V9.84zM2.4 2.4v7.44V2.4v27.2z" fill="#b69ee0"/></svg>
    
    <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
    <small class="text-muted">And some small print.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
    <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
    <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
  </a>
</div>
</div>



        


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the elements with a container `div` with `d-flex` and `align-items-center` classes and for the text elements you can also surround with a container `div` and give it some `margin-left` with `ms-3`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/> <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z"/> </svg>        
&nbsp;Create new Workflow
</button>
        

<div class="dropdown-menu p-0 border-0" style="width: max-content;">
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="32" width="25.6"><path d="M6.36 25.2h12.88v-2.4H6.36zm0-6.8h12.88V16H6.36zM2.4 32q-.96 0-1.68-.72Q0 30.56 0 29.6V2.4Q0 1.44.72.72 1.44 0 2.4 0h14.44l8.76 8.76V29.6q0 .96-.72 1.68-.72.72-1.68.72zM15.64 9.84V2.4H2.4v27.2h20.8V9.84zM2.4 2.4v7.44V2.4v27.2z" fill="#b69ee0"/></svg>
    <div class="ms-3">
      <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
      <small class="text-muted">And some small print.</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
    <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br/>
    <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
  </a>
</div>
</div>



        


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

You can use Bootstrap’s grid system.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z" />
          <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" /> </svg>
        &nbsp;Create new Workflow
      </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 border-0" style="width: max-content;">
      <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="col-1">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="32" width="25.6">
                <path d="M6.36 25.2h12.88v-2.4H6.36zm0-6.8h12.88V16H6.36zM2.4 32q-.96 0-1.68-.72Q0 30.56 0 29.6V2.4Q0 1.44.72.72 1.44 0 2.4 0h14.44l8.76 8.76V29.6q0 .96-.72 1.68-.72.72-1.68.72zM15.64 9.84V2.4H2.4v27.2h20.8V9.84zM2.4 2.4v7.44V2.4v27.2z" fill="#b69ee0" /></svg>
          </div>
          <div class="col-11">
            <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br />
            <small class="text-muted">And some small print.</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br />
        <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="p-2 list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <span class="">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</span><br />
        <small class="text-muted">And some muted small print.</small>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the flex-direction to a column so that all items are centered. Then use flex to position the whole text container

Some placeholder content in a paragraph.
        And some small print.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).